# Reference: Looking for a concise treatise on the matrix ring $\mathbf{Mat}_{m\times m}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, cryptography

There are good books on matrix theory over $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ and even arbitrary fields. (See 
[First course in linear algebra and matrices over arbitrary fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516659/first-course-in-linear-algebra-and-matrices-over-arbitrary-fields?rq=1) for details)

My question is: Is there a book focus on matrix theory over the ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$? In particular, when $n$ is a large integer and its factorization is unknown, what about the computational problems over this matrix ring $R=\mathbf{Mat}_{m\times m}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$? Say, computing the inverse, square roots, determinant, eigenvalues, etc. of a given matrix.